# Ansible set_facts by localhost json file and copy to remote hosts

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to copy a json file from my localhost to remote hosts, and use the json "version" key value as a parameter in the destination file name.

JSON:

```
{"name": "test", "version": 3}
```

YML:

```
---
- name: Get json file version
  hosts: locahost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Register licenses file
      command: "cat conf/licenses.json"
      register: result

    - name: Save the json data
      set_fact:
        jsondata: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Save licenses file version
      set_fact:
        file_version: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: 'version'

- name: Deploy Licenses File
  hosts: hosts
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Copy licenses file
      copy:
        src: "conf/licenses.json"
        dest: "/tmp/licenses_{{ file_version }}.json"
```

When I run the playbook above, the Deploy Licenses File key doesn't find the file_version fact, even though I can see it is successfully saved in the Get json file version key.

Set file_version fact:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "file_version": "1"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'file_version' is undefined
```

I think the facts are saved on the given host granularity and are not global facts per playbook initiation.

My current workaround is to combine the keys to a single task and then it works correctly, but I prefer to get the version once instead of repeating it for each remote host.

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format, which is what you have. Is that a type or caused by you using `.yml` as file extension ( The [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006.)

Comment: The file extension I'm using is .yml (it's not a typo). Thanks for letting me know. Do you think my issue is related to the file type? @Anthon

Comment: The file type unlikely has anything to do with that, It is more likely that ansible has some expectations on what is in the YAML document, but I am not familiar with ansible, so I have no idea.

Comment: @Anthon `.yml` is a file extension of YAML file, the markup language you are raising seems to be [`.yml2`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/yml2)

Comment: Yes `.yml` is an extension that can be used for a YAML file, so is `.json` and `.py`. But none of those have been recommended (at least not for the last 15 years)

Comment: @Anthon if using `.yml` extension for yaml files was not recommended at all and could potentially cause issues in the last 15 years, most IDEs would not group `.yaml` and `.yml` together to render both with same syntax highlighting using the same plugin, and most Ansible official and community roles/collections would be totally broken, as well as a lot of tools like gitlab-ci, .travis-ci, pylint, yamlint, kubectl, docker-compose (and the list is still very long)

Comment: @Zeitounator `.yaml` is the extension recommended on yaml.org, the website where the YAML specification is posted. Of course there are people and organisations that are slower than others to pick up on recommendations (and standards like YAML 1.2). For docker-compose e.g. `.yaml` is preferred, but `.yml` accepted. That is IMO the right approach, and that should not take 15+ years to implement.

Comment: My point is that it is a de-facto notoriously accepted standard over the last decade and beyond that you can use any of those two extensions (your `docker-compose` example is a brilliant demonstration of this) and that this is hence off-topic for a solution to the current problem. Moreover, the yaml.org site gives this as a recommendation (i.e. `whenever possible`), not as a requirement. All tools, past and future, will most probably continue to accept both since this is now generally and widely accepted, like any raw text editor should recognize `.txt` and `.text` by default,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access facts of another host, you can always use the `hostvars` [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

So, in your case:

```yaml
dest: "/tmp/licenses_{{ hostvars.localhost.file_version }}.json"
```

---

Now, you actually do not need that level of complication with two plays and could well do:

```yaml
- name: Deploy Licenses File
  hosts: hosts
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Copy licenses file
      copy:
        src: "{{ _licence_file }}"
        dest: "/tmp/licenses_{{ file_version }}.json"
      vars:
        _licence_file: conf/licenses.json
        file_version: >-
          {{ (lookup('file', _licence_file) | from_json).version }}
```

Comment: Thanks ! using hostvars did the trick ! I'll try to improve it into a single play as you offered.

Answer (score 1):

The first play runs at *localhost* only. Therefore the variables declared in the first play are available to *localhost* only. This is the reason that the variables are not available to *host* in the second play

> The error was: 'file_version' is undefined

Run once the tasks in a block of the first play at *all* hosts. This way the variables will be available to all hosts in the second play. For example, the simplified playbook below does the job

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - include_vars:
            file: licenses.json
            name: jsondata
        - set_fact:
            file_version: "{{ jsondata.version }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: hosts
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: licenses.json
        dest: "/tmp/licenses_{{ file_version }}.json"
```

Created file at the remote host

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/licenses_3.json
{"name": "test", "version": 3}
```

The code can be further simplified. The single play below does the job as well

```yaml
- hosts: hosts
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: licenses.json
        name: jsondata
      run_once: true
    - copy:
        src: licenses.json
        dest: "/tmp/licenses_{{ jsondata.version }}.json"
```